# percent match within the same table

Tags: mysql, php

Below I have an MySQL database where "id" is just an id for each row. "question" shows the id of the question. There are four questions, 11, 12, 13 and 14. For every question the user has four answer options (1,2,3 and 4) which is stored in the "answer" column. The "user" column indicates what user who answered. In this example we have user 10, 11 and 12

```
id      question    answer      user
1           11          2       10  
2           12          2       10
3           13          3       10
4           14          4       10
5           11          2       11
6           12          2       11
7           13          4       11
8           14          1       11
9           11          2       12          
10          12          2       12  
11          13          1       12
12          14          1       12
```

Let's say that user 10 is the reference user which means that I want to know how well user 10 matches with the others. Using SQL and/or php code how can I match the answers of the users such that I get the matches in percent with the highest percent shown first. So in this example I'm looking for something like.

The Matches of user 10

```
        user     percent    
1       11       50%
2       12       75%
```

Comment: Sounds wrong.  Please explain the math for the 75%.  ((2=2) + (2=2) + (3=1) + (4=1)) / 4 = 50%.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a subquery (`q1`) to count how many answers of every user coincide with those of user 10 (`number_of_coinciding_answers`). Then, have a second subquery (`q2`) that counts the `number_of_answers`.

Then compute `100.0 * number_of_coinciding_answers / number_of_answers`:

Everything put together just looks like:

```
SELECT
    q1.user, 
    100.0 * q1.number_of_coinciding_answers / q2.number_of_answers AS percent
FROM
    (SELECT
        t.user, 
        count(good.answer) AS number_of_coinciding_answers
    FROM
        t 
        JOIN t AS good ON good.question = t.question 
                      AND good.user = 10 
                      AND good.answer = t.answer
    WHERE
        t.user <> 10
    GROUP BY
        t.user
    ) AS q1
    CROSS JOIN
    (SELECT
        count(*) AS number_of_answers
    FROM
        t
    WHERE 
        t.user = 10
    ) AS q2  
ORDER BY
    q1.user ;
```

You'll get

```
user |  percent
---: | -------:
  11 | 50.00000
  12 | 50.00000
```

Note that the `JOIN` condition is taking care of just finding matching answers between the current user and the reference user (user 10).

Note also that the numbers retrieived are 50% and 50%, which are the correct ones, as pointed out by Rick James.

---

You can write it in a slightly more compact fashion (that MySQL actually seems to handle better) by using:

```
SELECT
    q1.user, 
    100.0 * q1.number_of_coinciding_answers / 
          (SELECT count(*) FROM  t WHERE  t.user = 10) AS percent
FROM
    (SELECT
        t.user, 
        count(good.answer) AS number_of_coinciding_answers
    FROM
        t 
        JOIN t AS good ON good.question = t.question 
                      AND good.user = 10 
                      AND good.answer = t.answer
    WHERE
        t.user <> 10
    GROUP BY
        t.user
    ) AS q1
ORDER BY
    q1.user ;
```

---

All these queries are helped by having a multi-column covering index on columns `(user, question, answer)`. That is, in MySQL, you'd define your table

```
CREATE INDEX idx_t_uqa 
    ON t (user, question, answer) ;
```

You can see a more step-by-step approach and all the settings at *dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=92481482882a0487e439e1db22deb4a3)*

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure there are many ways to do this. Here's one:

```
CREATE TABLE QA (id int, question int, answer int, user int);

INSERT INTO QA
VALUES (1, 11, 2, 10)
      ,(2, 12, 2, 10)
      ,(3, 13, 3, 10)
      ,(4, 14, 4, 10)
      ,(5, 11, 2, 11)
      ,(6, 12, 2, 11)
      ,(7, 13, 4, 11)
      ,(8, 14, 1, 11)
      ,(9, 11, 2, 12)
      ,(10, 12, 2, 12)
      ,(11, 13, 1, 12)
      ,(12, 14, 1, 12)
;

SET @QCount := (SELECT COUNT(*) as QCount from QA WHERE QA.user = 10);
SET @QCount := IF(@QCount = 0, NULL, @QCount);

SELECT q1.user, ROUND(COUNT(a1.answer) * 100.0 / @QCount, 1) as percent
  FROM QA q1
         LEFT  JOIN QA a1 ON (    q1.question = a1.question
                              AND q1.answer = a1.answer
                              AND a1.user = 10
                             )
 WHERE q1.user <> 10
 GROUP BY q1.user
;
```

Tested via this [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5s6W4afj5QsboCTYdx39uS/0)

Here's how it works:

I am assuming that (in this case, at least) user `10`'s answers should be considered to be the answer key. We select the number of questions for that user to get the total question count.

Then, for each other user who has at least one answer, we get all the answers for each user, and `LEFT JOIN` them to the answer key questions *and answers*. If the answer key answer and the user's answer don't match, then the left join fails to find a match.

So, for all the right answers, we have a matched row from the answer key; for the wrong answers, we have the user's answer row, with no matched row.

We then count the number of matched rows for each user. The `COUNT` function doe snot count values that are NULL; by counting on a column from the `LEFT JOIN` table (the answer key), we'll only get a count of the right answers. NOTE: if, for some reason, there's no answer for some questions for a given those won't exists and won't be counted; so, they'll be treated as wrong answers.

To get the percentage of right answers, we simply multiply the number of wrong answers by 100, and divide by the total number of questions in the answer key. I leave the formatting aspect of showing an actual percent symbol up to the user, if required.

Note that the actual results are 50% for users 11 and 12; you showed 75% for one, bit the answers in your sample data show only two right for each user.